# Does Uniformly parabolic PDE has always a strong solution?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

Is it always true that a uniformly parabolic PDE has a strong solution in $\mathcal{C}^{1,2}([0,T)\times (a,b);\mathbb{R})$?
My example is the following: 
$g_t(t,y)+ \mu(t,y)g_y(t,y)+\frac{1}{2}\beta^2y^2g_{yy}(t,y)-q(t) g(t,y) + f(t,y)=0 \quad (t,y) \in [0,T), \times (a,b)$. 
with boundary conditions
$\begin{cases}
g(t,0)=F, t \in [0,T] \\
g(T,y)= \max\{F-Ay,S\}
\end{cases}$
where the functions $\mu,f,q$ are continuous and bounded. I know that I have a viscosity solution and that this solution is unique. How can I conclude that this solution is in $\mathcal{C}^{1,2}([0,T)\times (a,b);\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail? I’m assuming that you’re thinking of linear PDE, but even then there are other details that will affect the answer. Are your coefficients bounded? Are you thinking of homogenous or nonhomogenous PDE and if it is nonhomogeneous are you assuming that the nonhomogeneous term is $L^2$? Does the solution need to satisfy inital/boundary conditions?

Comment: I edited the question with some more details :D